# Clone AWS elastic beanstalk environment failed

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I had always successfully created new environment by clone environment from a healthy running environment. But suddenly start get failures since today. Is there are limitation for clone environment for one account? Can you please give me some comments on this error?

[image]

Comment: There is some warning about different version? maybe this is the issue?

Comment: @Marcin This warning has been there for long time. The issue happens since today.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is caued by insufficient resources. When the environment is created, a log bucket for logging needs to be created in S3. But the S3 bucket already has the maximum number of buckets and not allowed new bucket created.